# CDF of sum of random variables in terms of CDF of

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $X, Y$ be random variables on a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. I'd like to write the cdf $F_{X+Y}$ of $X + Y$ in terms of the cdfs $F_X$ and $F_Y$.

This is my approach

$$F_{X+Y}(z) = \mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq z) = \mathbb{E}[1_{\{X + Y \leq z\}}] = \int 1_{\{X + Y \leq z\}} \,d\mathbb{P}$$

How can I proceed at this point?

Comment: Does the convolutional form satisfy your requirement?: $$F_{X+Y}=P(X\leq z-Y)=\int\int F_X(z-y)dF_Y(y)dx$$,

where $dF_Y(y)=f_Y(y)dy$ when the density exists.

Comment: @AlexR. It does but how can I derive this equation? The first equality is clear.

Comment: Btw that assumes independence. You can derive it by conditioning on $Y=y$.

Comment: I get this $\mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq z) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq z - Y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq z - y, Y = y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq z - y) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y = y)$

Comment: Right but when you condition, you need to integrate. You're using the fact that $P(X,Y) = \int P(X|Y=y)P(Y=y)$

Comment: Thank you! I don't even need the condition. I can just write $\mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq z) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq z - Y) = \int \mathbb{P}(X \leq z - Y) \,d\mathbb{P} = \int \mathbb{P}(x \leq z - y) \,d\mathbb{P}^Y = \int F_X(z-y) \,d\mathbb{P}^Y$.